# Regular expression to catch all key value pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a string and I'm trying to get all key-value pairs, (please note that the key names may be repeated, --task_parameters).

I was able to get some of the key-value pairs however my regex is not sophisticated enough to fetch it correctly.

```
keys = re.findall(r'--\S+', str)
values = re.findall(r'\$\{\S+', str)
```

```
str = '--client \'jENNY\' \\\n                        --url_to_use "${URL}" \\\n    --script \'path/to/my/script.py\' \\\n                        --name ${NAME} \\\n                        --id ${ID} \\\n --build ${BUILD} \\\n      --part \'Star - Trek\'     \\\n                        --sequence_name \'test_sequence\' \\\n     --task_parameters \'{"ENV_VARS": {"SKIP": "1", "TEST": "1", "REUSE": "0"}, "ARGUMENTS": {"--mode": "test", "--bind": "True", "--skip_stats": "True"}, "NAME": "R_eCAp"}\' \\\n                        --task_parameters \'{"TASK_ARGUMENTS": {"-t": "new/path/script.py", "--test": "\'"${RESOURCE}"\'", "-k": "ASpace2001Odessy"}, "NAME": "Run", "LAUNCH": {"TIMER": 42}}\' \\\n                        --custom \'r2d2.xml\' \\\n       --task_parameters \'{"NAME": "Posts", "ARGUMENTS": {"--priority": "P1"}}\' \\'
```

I had thought of using regex as I had believed that there was a pattern as to when I looked at it earlier it seemed like all the keys started with "--"(which is mostly true; apart from "--priority", "--test", etc) and all the values were inside "${}".

However, it turns out I was incorrect. Some key pairs like "client", "script" value is not within {} also "--task_parameters" results are nested so entire `{"TASK_ARGUMENTS": {"-t": "new/path/script.py", "--test": "\'"${RESOURCE}"\'", "-k": "ASpace2001Odessy"}, "NAME": "Run", "LAUNCH": {"TIMER": 42}}` is the value.

I'm storing keys, values as separate arrays as I'm zipping and looping over later.

How should I proceed next? Is there a pattern I'm missing? Also, I don't need "--" before the key name, I was thinking of removing it post-processing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to parse command line arguments. Have you looked into stdlib's [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)? To better help you, it would be useful to know where your input string comes from. It doesn't seem to be well formatted. For example, `--script \path/to/my/script.py\'` seems like it should be `--script \'path/to/my/script.py\'`, with an escaped single quote before `path`. The `\\\n` also seem weird.

**Edit**:

OK, for more info on this code, check argparse and shlex modules from the standard library:

```py
import argparse
import shlex

text = '--client \'jENNY\' \\\n                        --url_to_use "${URL}" \\\n    --script \'path/to/my/script.py\' \\\n                        --name ${NAME} \\\n                        --id ${ID} \\\n --build ${BUILD} \\\n      --part \'Star - Trek\'     \\\n                        --sequence_name \'test_sequence\' \\\n     --task_parameters \'{"ENV_VARS": {"SKIP": "1", "TEST": "1", "REUSE": "0"}, "ARGUMENTS": {"--mode": "test", "--bind": "True", "--skip_stats": "True"}, "NAME": "R_eCAp"}\' \\\n                        --task_parameters \'{"TASK_ARGUMENTS": {"-t": "new/path/script.py", "--test": "\'"${RESOURCE}"\'", "-k": "ASpace2001Odessy"}, "NAME": "Run", "LAUNCH": {"TIMER": 42}}\' \\\n                        --custom \'r2d2.xml\' \\\n       --task_parameters \'{"NAME": "Posts", "ARGUMENTS": {"--priority": "P1"}}\''

# make text single line and remove superfluous \\:
text = text.replace('\n', '')
text = text.replace('\\', '')

# it seems like it's using shell syntax, so we'll use
# shlex to split those in the right places:
arguments = shlex.split(text)

# create the argument parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--client')
parser.add_argument('--url_to_use')
parser.add_argument('--script')
parser.add_argument('--name')
parser.add_argument('--id')
parser.add_argument('--build')
parser.add_argument('--part')
parser.add_argument('--custom')
parser.add_argument('--sequence_name')
# append means "add repetitions to a list"
parser.add_argument('--task_parameters', action='append')

args = parser.parse_args(arguments)
# these are your key values, but remember that
# args.task_parameters is a list
for key, value in vars(args).items():
    print(key, value)
```

This code prints:

```
client jENNY
url_to_use ${URL}
script path/to/my/script.py
name ${NAME}
id ${ID}
build ${BUILD}
part Star - Trek
custom r2d2.xml
sequence_name test_sequence
task_parameters ['{"ENV_VARS": {"SKIP": "1", "TEST": "1", "REUSE": "0"}, "ARGUMENTS": {"--mode": "test", "--bind": "True", "--skip_stats": "True"}, "NAME": "R_eCAp"}', '{"TASK_ARGUMENTS": {"-t": "new/path/script.py", "--test": "${RESOURCE}", "-k": "ASpace2001Odessy"}, "NAME": "Run", "LAUNCH": {"TIMER": 42}}', '{"NAME": "Posts", "ARGUMENTS": {"--priority": "P1"}}']
```

Comment: I had made a typo while posting the path, thanks for pointing it out! I've made the edit now.

Comment: I've edited the answer with some code that I think does what you need.